# Find the equation of the cubic

Tags: calculus

Find the equation of the cubic $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ that passes through $(0,-6)$, $(1,-2)$ and tangent on the line $3x - y = 6$ at $(2,0)$.

I've substituted every point in the equation of the cubic. And I've only got d = - 6 by substituting point (0-6), the equations a + b + c + d = -2 (from point (1,-2)) and 8a + 4b + 2c + d = 0 (from point (2,0))

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to use the information given to find the equation of the cubic? It is considered bad form to just post the problem, without explaining what you have tried, as it is not clear how to help you, or even that people should make the effort, without knowing what you have attempted, and where you are at.

Comment: I've substituted every point in the equation of the cubic. And I've only got d = - 6 by substituting point (0-6), the equations a + b + c + d = -2 (from point (1,-2)) and 8a + 4b + 2c + d = 0 (from point (2,0))

Comment: That would be good information to include in our post, for future reference, so that we know what you've tried / where you are - I wrote up some details on how to continue the problem, let me know if anything in it isn't clear.

Comment: Already got the answer, $y = x^3 - 4x^2 + 7x - 6$ Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the cubic passes through the point $(0,-6)$, we have that $d = -6$. Similarly, in passing through the point $(1,-2)$, we have that $a+b+c+d = -2$, so that $a+b+c = 4$. Now, if the cubic is tangent on the line $3x-y = 6$ at $(2,0)$ we know that: 1. the cubic passes through the point $(2,0)$, and 2. at $(2,0)$, the derivative of the cubic agrees with the slope of the tangent line. Condition 1. gives us that $8a + 4b + 2c + d = 0 \implies 4a + 2b + c = 3$, and condition 2. gives us that $\{ 3ax^2 + 2bx + c \}_{x = 2} = 3$ (as the slope of the tangent line is $3$), or rather
$
3 = 12a + 4b + c.
$ 
So now, solve the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
a+b+c=4\\
4a+2b+c=3\\
12a+4b+c=3 .\\
\end{cases}
$$